# Python check if file exists in two places and run if found in any of them

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to create a script for python 3.6 that checks if teamviewer.exe is installed in any of the two places it can be found (in x64 os it's installed in Program files(x86) ) and if found in any of the two places to run it
This is what i came up with so far

```
import os
import subprocess
os.path.exists('C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer.exe')
```

using `subprocess.run('C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer.exe')` gives me errors.
any clues?

Comment: Usually when a problem statement contains an English 'if', the Python solution contains a Python `if`...

Comment: at this momment I'm trying to get it working at least with one since path...baby steps.

Comment: ... and you still need an `if`.

Comment: You're also going to want to escape the backslashes (e.g. `exists('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamViewer.exe')`.

Comment: import os
    import subprocess
    if os.path.exists('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamViewer.exe'):
        subprocess.run('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamViewer.exe')
this is what i got now..sorry about the format but I have no ideea how to introduce as code in a comment. problem is no error is given, teamviewer still won't start.

Comment: You can edit you post with new code rather than stuffing it in your comment. If it doesn't start it's probably because it doesn't exist...

Comment: I'm stupid. thank you very much.
how would i go now to check in two places and run it from wichever place it is found?

Comment: how would i go now to check in two places and run it from wichever place it is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using "//"
I tried "subprocess.call('C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe')"
it worked.

Comment: already fixed that part. now I need the script to looki in two locations:
`C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TeamViewer.exe`
or
`C:\\Program Files\\TeamViewer.exe`
and then run it from wichever location it is found it